# How do I open this FPC connector?

Tags: components, fpc

I struggle to remove the FPC from this connector. I could not find anything like that in [this digi list](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/399?k=&pv69=352&FV=1b4c0008%2Cfff40016%2Cfff80421%2C1600012&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25), and I am afraid to damage it.

The connector is 15mm wide and I have found it in an Olympus PEN camera.
[image] Most of the connectors in this camera are quite regular and can be easily opened by pushing a plastic part. A few are like this. This one connects the back LCD, which I am attempting to replace.

EDIT: I tried the likely solutions (trying to flap the top or the bottom half), pulling (gently) on the FPC, but without success. I don't want to risk breaking or damaging the connector by applying too much force; I hope someone will recognize this particular model / type of the connector.

Comment: These gray things on the sides. I think you can pull them. The right one seem damaged though

Comment: In which direction? (they seem to be metal)

Comment: To left and right. Metal? Well, then probably it's not that.

Comment: Does not seem to move.

Comment: Well.. you can just try pulling out the cable :) Sometimes it is that simple.

Comment: Does the grey plastic flap at the top of the picture flip upwards?

Comment: Or does the bottom half flip upwards? Can't really tell which way around it would go, but there's something that looks like a hinge in there.

Comment: I guess my question is: do you know this particular specific connector and know for sure what one should flap / pull / etc?

Comment: I think those grey holders push up in this image, then the top flap should flip up.

Comment: Can you take a picture from a different angle..i.e. the side .. up close

Comment: GOT it, the upper grey flap goes up. @Felthry, can you please formulate an answer, so I can vote it up?

Comment: @January There you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this sort of connector a few times. What you want to do is pull upwards on the grey flap on the top of the image (though it could also be the bottom half that flips up, I've seen both ways) and once that's up, it releases the spring pressure on the flat flex and lets it slide out easily.

I'm not sure if there's a name for this sort of connector, but they're common, at least in my experience, in laptops. I think they tend to have a lower profile than other sorts of flex connector, and they are much easier to insert the flex into than friction-held connectors.